# CSS in ie only works with dev tools

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Been enjoying all the excellent answers on here for a while and now it's time for myself to hopefully get an answer for my question.

I'm working on a web site with some pretty tight design. Works great in FF but when it comes to IE I have problems with the content not showing.

The content that gives me problems is placed in width and height specific divs. Some of the content renderes properly but not all.

I tried to use the IE dev tools and found that if I disable and/or enable any css rule the content will be rendered properly in IE.
I can't figure out if the problem is in my css or an issue with my ie/bootcamp install.

Should say that I run IE on a bootcamp partition on mac. Don't know if that has any impact on the issue.

IE version is 8

Anyone experienced similar issues?

Comment: IE version?  There are about 4 major versions currently in significant use.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that. it's IE 8

Comment: My coworkers saw problems in their IE Tester browsers that didn't exist in my Multiple_IE install or in VMs from Microsoft. That's part of the reason why I still use a MS OS /cry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, seems like it was a bug in IE/Dev Tools that somehow had to do with relative positioning.

My CSS didn't work even though it seemed to when i enabled/disable any css rule through the dev tools.

The fix was pure css and had nothing to do with IE, Dev Tools or my bootcamp installation.

However, it does seem like I stumbled upon another bug in IE/Dev tools, that is, the fact that enabling or disabling a random css rule can change the rendering of of the entire page. I don't have time to investigate this at all so hopefully the right people are already aware of this and working on fixing it.

Thanks for the help everyone.